# ArticleBundle Draft article list visibility

Tags: sulu

Helo, developers...

I am using SULU CMS, and as an option I installed ArticleBundle... Now, it is, basically working, but I have strange thing going on...

Everything I am describing now is in admin panel (no FE is involved in my problem)

- **(New published article)** *** I click on Articles menu, it opens list of existing articles, and it shows all my published articles... When I click on ADD, form that opens is fine, it works, I fill in all needed data, and then, when I click Save and Publish, it saves, and it is OK... When I return to list of articles, that article is visible and editable..
- **(New Draft article)** *** I click on Articles menu, it opens list of existing articles........ I click Add.... and when I click Save as Draft it saves article (I have UUID in url that I copy), but, when I return to list of articles, **that DRAFT article is not shown** in list... When I use link, directly (by entering UUID I got when creating article), it opens normally, editable, and when I click Save and Publish it works as it should be..

Please, If someone can help me how to get, also, Draft articles in initial list of articles, so I can click and edit it, and publish, too...

Answer (score 0):

First check your User-Role if all article-bundle security rules are added.
Watch out there is a section "Article types" and a section "Globals" which are restricting your access to article-types and articles in general.

When this brings no change, do you have multiple article types and just open the wrong type tab or have no "all" tab (added by configuration).

For further investigation your Sulu, ArticleBundle and ElasticSearch versions would be appreciated.